# How to use quiet mode in clickhouse version 18.12.17

Tags: clickhouse

**I want to know the new way for surpressing error messages**

**Old version**

```
> clickhouse-local --version
ClickHouse client version 1.1.54390.

> clickhouse-local --help | grep "\-s"
-s [ --silent ]           quiet mode, do not print errors
```

Sample code in old version: not producing error message

```
> clickhouse-local -s -q "select now("
```

**New version**

```
> clickhouse-local --version
ClickHouse client version 18.12.17.
```

Sample code in new version: produces error message. Setting **send_logs_level=none is not helping**

```
> clickhouse-local --send_logs_level none -q "select now("
Code: 62, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 11: (. Unmatched parentheses: (, e.what() = DB::Exception
```

Comment: After checking with my colleague the problem was more about suppressing status messages. Seems those have been reduced in the newer version anyways and can be shown if wanted with "--verbose". The question how to suppress error messages might be interesting in general anyways.

Answer (score 0):

you can just redirect stderr into /dev/null

`clickhouse-local -q "select now(" 2>/dev/null`

this command will return exit code but will not return error message

Comment: Right, but I want to do that as an option, since I am actually defining the command in the config and pasting the query later to it and was hoping for a simple solution. Might not be best practice but thats how our legacy code was built initially.